# Foo cannot be cast to Foo

Tags: java, casting

I am looping through `ArrayList<Bar>`. `Foo` extends `Bar`.  I'm trying to find an instance of `Foo` in the list.

```
ArrayList<Bar> list = new ArrayList<Bar>();

// fill list with items that are instances of Foo and Bar

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
  Bar bar = list.get(i);

  if (bar.getClass().getName().equals("com.me.Foo")) // "if(bar instanceof Foo)" never passes
  {
    System.out.println("bar is an instance of Foo");
    Foo foo = (Foo) bar;
  }
}
```

If this section of code gets run I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.me.Foo cannot be cast to com.me.Foo
// stack
```

However, in another spot, I have a method that returns an instance of `Bar` and I can check to see if it's an instance of `Foo` using `instanceof` and then cast `Bar` to `Foo` with no problems:

```
Bar bar = returnBar(); // returns an instance of Bar, but the variable 
                       // it returns could be an instance of Foo
if (bar instanceof Foo)
{
  System.out.println("bar is an instance of Foo");
  Foo foo = (Foo) bar;
}
```

What is different here?

Here's the real source of the issue:
http://pastie.org/private/jhyhovn7mm4ghxlxsmweog

I'm working with an API called Bukkit which allows for custom plugins for servers for a game called Minecraft.  The documentation can be found [here](http://jd.bukkit.org/doxygen/) for those really interested in the  issue.  I'm going to go to the official Bukkit forums and try my question there, since it is becoming more of an API specific issue, but I'll leave all this here for those that were interested in the problem.

Comment: do they both inherit from the same baseclass?

Comment: could you please provide the IDEOne demo for your issue ? http://ideone.com

Comment: I see two classes in your code. Foo and Bar. Do they both inherit from same baseclass?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, however, I'm going to be using my real world example.  I'll post in the main question when it's ready.

Comment: This code ran for me on Java 1.6. I hadn't expected it, but it did run.

Comment: @Asdfg Ah thanks for clarifying.  Wasn't sure if you were talking about the variables that are in the `ArrayList` and the one received by `returnBar()` or the classes.  The answer is yes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is that you're loading `Foo` from two places. In your loop, try printing out `bar.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `Foo.class.getClassLoader()`. I suspect they'll show different classloaders. (It's possible that you've got two classloaders loading from the same place, of course, which is equally bad.)

Basically, as far as the JVM is concerned, two classes with the same name loaded from different classloaders are entirely different - you can't cast from one to the other. Assuming I'm right about this, the usual solution is to try to work out *why* they're being loaded from different classloaders, and fix that.

Note that when you use `instanceof` instead, that checks whether the types are really compatible, so it *will* notice the different classloaders.

Comment: Seems like a good likelihood.  If instanceof is failing, forcing the issue by name isn't likely to fix it any, just help reveal the underlying problem.  I've also seen this problem in a dirty build, make sure you've cleaned the build thoroughly.  This can also happen if you have conflicting jars with com.me.Foo also I believe.

Comment: I haven't come across such situation yet, What could be the reason jvm picks different class loader by itself?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: It can be an issue in webapps, where you've got different code running from various different classloaders, which end up getting quite complicated. (It often happens with library classes - e.g. if you've got log4j in both a war file *and* the container classloader.)

Comment: You are correct, it appears that they are being loaded by two different classloaders.  Thanks for the help :)